# HTTP/2: stream.end using For-Loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, stream, http2

#### *How can a stream be closed within a `for-loop`?*

I am attempting a HTTP/2 resource `push-stream` within a loop by reading a `.json` config file. If there is only one resource in the `resurce.file,type`, the push is successful. If there are more than one resource in the config, only the first resource listed is pushed and the remaining resource(s) are not pushed & the client never receives the remaining files and will not finish parsing.

I am thinking that only the first resource stream ends and the remaining open streams are not closing.

**I commented as best as I believe the code should be functioning:**

```js
// Verify if client can be pushed to:
if (res.push) {

  // Read what resources should be pushed via config.json5:
  for(var i = 0; i < confg.resource.length; i++) {

    // Compare what URL requested the resources & pass the relevant files:
    if (req.url == confg.resource[i].url) {

      // Request the resource(s) to stream:
      var ps  = fs.readFileSync('../build' + confg.resource[i].file)

          // Push the relevant resource stream(s):
        , stream = res.push(confg.resource[i].file
        , { // ..and set the content type;
            res: {'content-type': confg.resource[i].type},
          });

      // Close the resource stream(s):
      stream.end(ps, function() {
        // TODO(CelticParser): Remove for production ->v
        console.log("Pushed Sream");
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**.config.json5:**

```json5
resource: [ // HTTP/2 Push-Streams
  { file: '/js/theme.min.js',
     type: 'script'
  },
  { file: '/css/theme.min.css',
    type: 'style',
    url:  '/'
  }
]
```

**Using the example above;**

If the `/js/theme.min.js` is listed first and the `/css/theme.min.css` is listed second in the config , the `/js/theme.min.js` will be loaded by the browser and the other file will not load and the client hangs up (*doesn't continue parsing*). If the the list order of the resources are swapped, the same thing occurs. If there is only one file listed in the config, everything works as expected.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `config.json5`. You are checking the requested url before passing the files here:

```
// Compare what URL requested the resources & pass the relevant files:
if (req.url == confg.resource[i].url) {
   ...
}
```

But in your json only one item can pass the test, the other one is missing the `url` property. Change your config to this (added `url:  '/'` to the first item) and it will work:

```
{
   resource : [
      { 
         file : '/js/theme.min.js',
         type : 'script',
         url  :  '/'
      },
      { 
         file : '/css/theme.min.css',
         type : 'style',
         url  :  '/'
      }
   ]
}
```

Tested with this small app, following the [http2 server example](https://github.com/molnarg/node-http2/blob/master/example/server.js), and also with your server code.

**server.js**

```
var fs      = require("fs");
var path    = require("path");
var http2   = require("http2");
var config  = require("./config.json");

var options = {
    key  : fs.readFileSync("./localhost.key"),
    cert : fs.readFileSync("./localhost.crt")
};

//----------------------------------------------------
http2.createServer(options, function(req, res) {

    if (res.push) {

        config.resource.forEach(function(resource){

            if (req.url === resource.url) {

                var push = res.push(resource.file, { res: {"content-type": resource.type } });
                push.writeHead(200);
                fs.createReadStream(path.join("../build", resource.file)).pipe(push);
            }
        });
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end();

}).listen(8080);
```

The `config.json` file contains the corrected config described above.

**Output**:

```
Receiving pushed resource: ./js/bootstrap.min.js -> /Developer/so/tests/push-0
Receiving pushed resource: ./css/bootstrap.min.css -> /Developer/so/tests/push-1
```

Comment: WOW! How did I miss that?? LOL Thnx!

Comment: Honestly, i also did..i built the whole server and client before noticing it :)

Comment: ..And I even moved that json block out of the `default.json5` to a `theme.json5` and didn't see it.  C&P is a bad habit.